# To catch adb logs after any crash comes in android device

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am doing set of steps using Android UIAutomator. (camera script to click 100 photos), so if any crash comes while in middle of process logs should start automatically and desired screenshot taken.

i want to capture adb logs and should be saved in device only

Is there a way to collect logs for a particular time and clear the logs and start the next test case and collect logs for that test case.

Comment: Create your own implementation logger class. So, instead of `Log.d()`, you can do `CustomLog.d()`. Write all input of `d()` method to a file. Or you can use crash-reporting tools such as Crashlytics, Firebase Crash Reporting.

Comment: i want to catch logs in phone memory only, also help to to show little code as i am new to UI automator and learning from internet only..